# Is there ever such a thing as too many listviews or adapters?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    //listviews
    ListView list;
    ListView torahList;
    ListView naviList;
    ListView ketuvimList;
    ListView bereshitList;
    ListView shemotList;
    ListView vayikraList;
    ListView bamidbarList;
    ListView devarimList;
    ListView yehoshuaList;
    ListView shoftimList;
    ListView shmuelAList;
    ListView shmuelBList;
    ListView melachimAList;
    ListView melachimBList;
    ListView yishayaList;
    ListView yirmiyahuList;
    ListView yechezkelList;
    ListView treiasarList;
    ListView hosheaList;
    ListView yoelList;
    ListView amosList;
    ListView ovadiyahList;
    ListView yonahList;
    ListView michahList;
    ListView nachumList;
    ListView chabakukList;
    ListView tzefaniyahList;
    ListView chaggaiList;
    ListView zechariyahList;
    ListView malachiList;
    ListView tehilimList;
    ListView mishleiList;
    ListView iyovList;
    ListView shirList;
    ListView rutList;
    ListView eichaList;
    ListView koheletList;
    ListView estherList;
    ListView danielList;
    ListView ezraList;
    ListView nechamyaList;
    ListView divreiaList;
    ListView divreibList;
//textviews
TextView hebrew;
TextView english;

//scrollview
ScrollView scroll;

//strings
String[] tanakh = {"Torah", "Navi", "Ketuvim"};
String[] torah = {"Bereshit", "Shemot", "Vayikra", "Bamidbar", "Devarim"};
String[] navi = {"Yehoshua", "Shoftim", "Shmuel Alef", "Shmuel Bet", "Melachim Alef", "Melachim Bet", "Yeshayahu", "Yirmayahu", "Yechezkel", "Trei-Asar"};
String[] ketuvim = {"Tehilim", "Mishlei", "Iyov", "Shir Hashirim", "Rut", "Eicha", "Kohelet", "Esther", "Daniel", "Ezra", "Nechamya", "Divrei Hayamim Alef", "Divrei Hayamim Bet"};
String[] bereshit = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet", "Perek Lamed", "Perek Lamed Alef", "Perek Lamed Bet", "Perek Lamed Gimel", "Perek Lamed Daled", "Perek Lamed Hey", "Perek Lamed Vav", "Perek Lamed Zayin", "Perek Lamed Chet", "Perek Lamed Tet", "Perek Mem", "Perek Mem Alef", "Perek Mem Bet", "Perek Mem Gimel", "Perek Mem Daled", "Perek Mem Hey", "Perek Mem Vav", "Perek Mem Zayin", "Perek Mem Chet", "Perek Mem Tet", "Perek Nun"};
String[] shemot = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet", "Perek Lamed", "Perek Lamed Alef", "Perek Lamed Bet", "Perek Lamed Gimel", "Perek Lamed Daled", "Perek Lamed Hey", "Perek Lamed Vav", "Perek Lamed Zayin", "Perek Lamed Chet", "Perek Lamed Tet", "Perek Mem"};
String[] vayikra = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin"};
String[] bamidbar = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet", "Perek Lamed", "Perek Lamed Alef", "Perek Lamed Bet", "Perek Lamed Gimel", "Perek Lamed Daled", "Perek Lamed Hey", "Perek Lamed Vav"};
String[] devarim = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet", "Perek Lamed", "Perek Lamed Alef", "Perek Lamed Bet", "Perek Lamed Gimel", "Perek Lamed Daled"};
String[] yehoshua = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled"};
String[] shoftim = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef"};
String[] shmuela = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet", "Perek Lamed", "Perek Lamed Alef"};
String[] shmuelb = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled"};
String[] melachima = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet"};
String[] melachimb = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey"};
String[] yishaya = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet", "Perek Lamed", "Perek Lamed Alef", "Perek Lamed Bet", "Perek Lamed Gimel", "Perek Lamed Daled", "Perek Lamed Hey", "Perek Lamed Vav", "Perek Lamed Zayin", "Perek Lamed Chet", "Perek Lamed Tet", "Perek Mem", "Perek Mem Alef", "Perek Mem Bet", "Perek Mem Gimel", "Perek Mem Daled", "Perek Mem Hey", "Perek Mem Vav", "Perek Mem Zayin", "Perek Mem Chet", "Perek Mem Tet", "Perek Nun", "Perek Nun Alef", "Perek Nun Bet", "Perek Nun Gimel", "Perek Nun Daled", "Perek Nun Hey", "Perek Nun Vav", "Perek Nun Zayin", "Perek Nun Chet", "Perek Nun Tet", "Perek Samech", "Perek Samech Alef", "Perek Samech Bet", "Perek Samech Gimel", "Perek Samech Daled", "Perek Samech Hey", "Perek Samech Vav"};
String[] yirmiyahu = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet", "Perek Lamed", "Perek Lamed Alef", "Perek Lamed Bet", "Perek Lamed Gimel", "Perek Lamed Daled", "Perek Lamed Hey", "Perek Lamed Vav", "Perek Lamed Zayin", "Perek Lamed Chet", "Perek Lamed Tet", "Perek Mem", "Perek Mem Alef", "Perek Mem Bet", "Perek Mem Gimel", "Perek Mem Daled", "Perek Mem Hey", "Perek Mem Vav", "Perek Mem Zayin", "Perek Mem Chet", "Perek Mem Tet", "Perek Nun", "Perek Nun Alef", "Perek Nun Bet"};
String[] yechezkel = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet", "Perek Lamed", "Perek Lamed Alef", "Perek Lamed Bet", "Perek Lamed Gimel", "Perek Lamed Daled", "Perek Lamed Hey", "Perek Lamed Vav", "Perek Lamed Zayin", "Perek Lamed Chet", "Perek Lamed Tet", "Perek Mem", "Perek Mem Alef", "Perek Mem Bet", "Perek Mem Gimel", "Perek Mem Daled", "Perek Mem Hey", "Perek Mem Vav", "Perek Mem Zayin", "Perek Mem Chet"};
String[] treiasar = {"Hoshea", "Yoel", "Amos", "Ovadiyah", "Yonah", "Michah", "Nachum", "Chabakuk", "Tzefaniyah", "Chaggi", "Zechariyah", "Malachi"};
String[] hoshea = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled"};
String[] yoel = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled"};
String[] amos = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet"};
String[] ovadiyah = {"Perek Alef"};
String[] yonah = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled"};
String[] michah = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin"};
String[] nachum = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel"};
String[] chabakuk = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel"};
String[] tzefaniyah = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel"};
String[] chaggai = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet"};
String[] zechariyah = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled"};
String[] malachi = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel"};
String[] tehilim = {"1-50", "51-100", "101-150"};
String[] mishlei = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet", "Perek Lamed", "Perek Lamed Alef"};
String[] iyov = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet", "Perek Lamed", "Perek Lamed Alef", "Perek Lamed Bet", "Perek Lamed Gimel", "Perek Lamed Daled", "Perek Lamed Hey", "Perek Lamed Vav", "Perek Lamed Zayin", "Perek Lamed Chet", "Perek Lamed Tet", "Perek Mem", "Perek Mem Alef", "Perek Mem Bet"};
String[] shir = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet"};
String[] rut = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled"};
String[] eicha = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey"};
String[] kohelet = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet"};
String[] esther = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud"};
String[] daniel = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet"};
String[] ezra = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud"};
String[] nechamya = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel"};
String[] divreia = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet"};
String[] divreib = {"Perek Alef", "Perek Bet", "Perek Gimel", "Perek Daled", "Perek Hey", "Perek Perek Vav", "Perek Zayin", "Perek Chet", "Perek Tet", "Perek Yud", "Perek Yud Alef", "Perek Yud Bet", "Perek Yud Gimel", "Perek Yud Daled", "Perek Tet Vav", "Perek Tet Zayin", "Perek Yud Zayin", "Perek Yud Chet", "Perek Yud Tet", "Perek Kuf", "Perek Kuf Alef", "Perek Kuf Bet", "Perek Kuf Gimel", "Perek Kuf Daled", "Perek Kuf Hey", "Perek Kuf Vav", "Perek Kuf Zayin", "Perek Kuf Chet", "Perek Kuf Tet", "Perek Lamed", "Perek Lamed Alef", "Perek Lamed Bet", "Perek Lamed Gimel", "Perek Lamed Daled", "Perek Lamed Hey", "Perek Lamed Vav"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    hebrew = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Hebrew);
    english = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.English);
    scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);

    //main listview
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Main);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tanakh);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setClickable(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //tanakh
            if (position == 0) {
                torahList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //navi
            if (position == 1) {
                naviList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //ketuvim
            if (position == 2) {
                ketuvimList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    //torah listview
    torahList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Torah);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, torah);
    torahList.setAdapter(adapter2);
    torahList.setClickable(true);
    torahList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            torahList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //bereshit
            if (position == 0) {
                bereshitList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //shemot
            if (position == 1) {
                shemotList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //vayikra
            if (position == 2) {
                vayikraList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //bamidbar
            if (position == 3) {
                bamidbarList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //devarim
            if (position == 4) {
                devarimList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });


    naviList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Navi);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, navi);
    naviList.setAdapter(adapter3);
    naviList.setClickable(true);
    naviList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            naviList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //yehoshua
            if (position == 0) {
                yehoshuaList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //shoftim
            if (position == 1) {
                shoftimList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //shmuel alef
            if (position == 2) {
                shmuelAList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //shmuel bet
            if (position == 3) {
                shmuelBList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //melachim alef
            if (position == 4) {
                melachimAList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //melachim bet
            if (position == 5) {
                melachimBList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //yeshayahu
            if (position == 6) {
                yishayaList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //yirmiyahu
            if (position == 7) {
                yirmiyahuList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //yechezkel
            if (position == 8) {
                yechezkelList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //trei-asaar
            if (position == 9) {
                treiasarList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    ketuvimList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Ketuvim);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ketuvim);
    ketuvimList.setAdapter(adapter4);
    ketuvimList.setClickable(true);
    ketuvimList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            ketuvimList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //tehilim
            if (position == 0) {
                tehilimList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //mishlei
            if (position == 1) {
                mishleiList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //iyov
            if (position == 2) {
                iyovList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //shir hashirim
            if (position == 3) {
                shirList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //rut
            if (position == 4) {
                rutList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //eicha
            if (position == 5) {
                eichaList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //kohelet
            if (position == 6) {
                koheletList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //esther
            if (position == 7) {
                estherList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //daniel
            if (position == 8) {
                danielList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //ezra
            if (position == 9) {
                ezraList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //nechamya
            if (position == 10) {
                nechamyaList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //divrei hayamim alef
            if (position == 11) {
            }
            //divrei hayamim bet
            if (position == 12) {
            }
        }
    });
    bereshitList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Bereshit);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bereshit);
    bereshitList.setAdapter(adapter5);
    bereshitList.setClickable(true);
    bereshitList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            scroll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bereshitList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            english.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            hebrew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (position == 0) {
                hebrew.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit1h));
                english.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit1e));
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                hebrew.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit2h));
                english.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit2e));
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                hebrew.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit3h));
                english.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit3e));
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                hebrew.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit4h));
                english.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit4e));
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                hebrew.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit5h));
                english.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit5e));
            }
            if (position == 5) {
                hebrew.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit6h));
                english.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit6e));
            }
            if (position == 6) {
                hebrew.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit7h));
                english.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit7e));
            }
            if (position == 7) {
                hebrew.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit8h));
                english.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit8e));
            }
            if (position == 8) {
                hebrew.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit9h));
                english.setText(getString(R.string.Bereshit9e));
            }
```

`I'm already starting to get messages from the emulator saying skipped 50 frames! My app currently has 45 adapters and 45 listviews. What I've been trying to set up is to have a menu- first it has 3 options, if the first is chosen then open these menus which leads to more options. It's like each one of them is each having a child but then that child has two children in analogical terms. Within the adapters I've been using if statements to get the positions of each button. Some if statements for some adapters can reach up to 50 if statements and some only having 10. Should I create a fragment for each listview so it's not running just on the onCreate method? Is it that I have a lot of strings?

Comment: With respect to the "skipped frames" message, use Traceview and `StrictMode` to see where you are spending your time.

Comment: Pretty much 1 is the right number for listviews.    Look up ExpandableListView for listviews with children

Comment: Thanks so much for responding would you be able to elaborate on how to do that? I'm a beginnner

Comment: Expandable listviews wouldn't work because I need about 4 generations

Comment: Then either you're building a really unique app, or you need to consider a redesign.  But in the first case you probably ought to be looking at writing a custom view.

Comment: And so you know-  every view on screen has a cost.  Even if hidden.  ANd every view with hildren has an even higher cost.  Doing lots of layouts and viewgroups and listviews is a great way to have bad performance.

Comment: I am trying to create a bible so that includes chapters, book name, and lots of other categories. How do you suppose I design this that would be most effective?

Comment: "What I've been trying to set up is to have a menu- first it has 3 options, if the first is chosen then open these menus which leads to more options." This sounds to me as if entirely new (list)activities/(list)fragments are required. You may be layering lots of views on top of each other simultaneously, which will leas to horrendous performance. Would you be able to post some code?

Comment: Just so you know I had a lot more code with a lot more listviews looking a lot like this.